# Auto supply user input ant exec task

Tags: ant, batch-file, dos

I have an ant script which runs an interactive (that requires 2 user inputs) dos batch file using exec task. I tried using attributes 'inputstring' (having 2 inputs (space in between, & in between)) and 'input' (file having 2 entries)

Only the first input is provided by exec task to the batch file, the script waits indefinitely for the second input.

is there a way to provide multiple inputs through exec task (or) 
is there a dos command to provide inputs for an interactive mode batch?

Snippet 1:

```
<exec dir="F:/upgrade" executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true" output="upgrade.out" inputstring ="no&amp;&amp;yes">                     
    <arg line="/c upgrade process F:/script"/>
</exec>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<exec dir="F:/upgrade" executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true" output="upgrade.out" input ="upgrade.input">                     
    <arg line="/c upgrade process F:/script"/>
</exec>
```

Input File content

```
no
yes
```

Comment: which version of ms-dos does java run on?

Comment: You should use input task => http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to simulate the press of "ENTER" into an single input. The code for "Enter" is the character '\n' in a lot of language. Its XML encoded form is the entity: `&#x0A;`.

So this should do the trick:

```
<exec dir="F:/upgrade" executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="true"
      output="upgrade.out" inputstring="no&#x0A;yes&#x0A;">                     
    <arg line="/c upgrade process F:/script"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nicolas. I tried the solution and it doesn't help the situation.